# Ant build NSIS fail

Tags: eclipse, ant, build, nsis

I'm trying to make the installer exe of a java project using it's build.xml from eclipse but the build fails.

```
[zip] Building zip: D:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Workspace\JDownloader\dist\JDownloader_windows_13312.zip
[echo] Clean Windows Setup...
[nsis] java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "makensis": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

This appears to be the section of build.xml that is failing:

```
<echo message="Clean Windows Setup..." />
  <nsis script="${exe.windows.script}" verbosity="2" />
  <echo message="Kikin Windows Setup..." /
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message

```
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

arises because Ant is unable to locate the script you are trying to run.

The script name (makensis? .nsi?) and location appear to be set in the Ant property `exe.windows.script`.  Suggest you check that is set, set as you expect, and that the script exists and is executable at that location.

*edit:* this is similar to an entry in the [Ant FAQ](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#CreateProcess_error_2):

> A common problem is not having the
>   executable on the PATH. In case you
>   get an error message Cannot run
>   program "...":CreateProcess error=2.
>   The system cannot find the path
>   specified. have a look at your PATH
>   variable.
>
> Just type the command directly on the
>   command line and if Windows finds it,
>   Ant should do it too. (Otherwise ask
>   on the user mailinglist for help.) If
>   Windows can not execute the program
>   add the directory of the programm to
>   the PATH (set
>   PATH=%PATH%;dirOfProgram) or specify
>   the absolute path in the executable
>   attribute in your buildfile.